# VideoView delays when starting to play a Multicast stream (just sometimes)

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I have a simple Android application which contains a WebView to load my Web_Based application and a VideoView to play Video (using HTTP protocol) and Multicast Stream (Live TV using UDP Protocol).

The Web_Based application, Video Server and Live TV Server are in a local Server (Ubuntu 12.04) and so my Android Application is connected to them locally with Ethernet Cable (Not via Internet).

Also my Android Device is a STB with Android Version 6.

The Android application is developed to play Video or Live TV when it is starts just by clicking on a button.But the issue is that JUST SOMETIMES, when I turn the STB on (and instantly starting the Android application), there is a delay for about 30 seconds to start Live TV. This issue is not happening for Video at all.

A sample of Live TV stream is udp://239.0.0.1:1234
A sample of Video url is http://192.168.200.235/test.mp4

// This is a pert of my main function to play UDP Stream

```
PlayerActivity.videoView.stopPlayback();
final Uri video = Uri.parse("udp://"+url.replaceAll("\\s+",""));
PlayerActivity.getInstance().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        PlayerActivity.videoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        PlayerActivity.videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        PlayerActivity.videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        PlayerActivity.videoView.start();

        PlayerActivity.videoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                Log.e("ERROR LOG FOR UDP STREAM",":( I don't get any error here !");
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: When I install the APK (I mean just for the first time that the app is running), there is no any problem. But after that irregularly I see the problem. Maybe it is just because of Cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Android can play UDP stream, but it's not built for this. So, it's better to use HSL or RTMP protocol for live stream playback and also for video file You can use HLS.